# Running Delta Issue in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

Data
Datapull | product | value
8/30 | X | 2
8/30 | Y | 3
8/30 | Y | 4
9/30 | X | 5
9/30 | Y | 6

Report
date range dimension: datapull
dimensions: data pull & product
metric: running delta of record count

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1IWP.jpg)

For 8/30, The totals to start for product Y are right but Product X shows nothing when the first row of data has an entry for product X in 8/30.

The variances in 9/30 are wrong too.

Can someone please let me know if there is a way to do running deltas with 2 dimensions? This is not calculating correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Using the combination of `Breakdown dimension` and `Running delta` calculation brakes the chart!

[image]

If you not mind to create a field for each `Breakdown dimension` (`product`), this will work:

```
case when product="X" then 1 else 0 end
```

And put each of these fields into 'Metric':

[image]

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution for this?